# Delta v/s United on international flight: quality v/s choice

Tags: loyalty-programs, united-airlines, klm, delta-air-lines, air-france

I have two choices available for my award travel on economy class. Both cost the same taxes and fee (well few dollars plus minus) and the same amount of miles. Question is which would you use - I know this is subjective but I want an opinion.

1. Delta from US to US, Delta from US to Paris/Amsterdam, Air France/KLM from Paris/Amsterdam to Delhi
2. United from US to US, United from US to Frankfurt, Lufthansa from Frankfurt to Delhi.
   Personally I hate American carriers like Delta, United and would chose European any day. But since this is an award travel and I have no complaints...  Both have the same time/money/stopvers, so it is a matter of preference now

Answer (score 3):

I travel with United quite often and have no complaints.

However, I would minimise the number of carriers involved, this simplifies things in the event of delays and cancellations, hence the Delta/Delta combination looks better to me.

--- added after the question changed ---

United/United v Delta/Delta I would next look at the specifics of the connections, especially inbound to the US if you are doing a return flight (immigration queues for non US passport holders can be long, and you clear immigration at point of entry). So first look at connection times, do any seem very rushed?

Comment: both have the same number of legs and carriers. My #2 had a typo.

Comment: I would also consider which airports. If one leg included somewhere like Chicago O'Hare, which is always a hassle to get through on time, I'd go with the alternative.

Comment: Roddy, good point. I was thinking of saying that, but then realised that I've had horrible times going through EWR and Atlanta too! Any favourites?

Answer (score 3):

AMS and Paris are both Delta hubs, whereas United does not have any hubs in Europe. This may be useful if you are delayed or have issues with your luggage, etc.

Other than that, you will most likely be flying your second leg on the codeshare partner, so really your only issue is how comfortable the flight is from US to Europe.

From the hubs to Delhi there are daily flights on the major carriers Air France / KLM / Lufthansa (with the exception of AF which doesn't fly on Sunday and Thursday); however only Lufthansa flies the A380 on this route (the other two fly the A330).

From personal experience, the A380 is much more comfortable in Economy class than the A330.

Given all else being equal, I would choose United/Lufthansa - simply because the A380 offers a better experience.

Comment: agree about A380!

Comment: Delta doesn't have hubs in Europe.  They just claim the KLM and AF hubs as their own.